# Docker can't pull images behind proxy server

Tags: linux, centos, docker, proxy, https

am using docker version 20.10.14 with CentOS Linux 7, i just installed docker and set up the proxy settings in /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service and my proxy settings are

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://10.330.100.100:3128/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.330.100.100:3128/"
Environment=no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

i get an error like

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

and when changing HTTPS_PROXY from https --> http i get

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Bad Request
```

and when trying to curl "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/" i get

```
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: i guess the question is if the proxy server doesnot support https is there a work around it?

Comment: "if the proxy server doesnot support https is there a work around" Nope, you need https support to pull from Docker Hub.

Comment: This appears to be an XY question, the problem isn't how to pull images over http, it's how to fix the proxy server to support https. For that we need details on the proxy server, not on the docker setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://10.330.100.100:3128/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.330.100.100:3128/"
                             ^                  ^^^^
```

Here you configure your proxy server to available over plain HTTP and HTTPS **on the same port**.  That is extremely unlikely to be the case.

Either your proxy server is configured with its own TLS certificate and will listen on different ports for http and https.

Or, and that is usually the case, the proxy server only supports plain http connections and requests to HTTPS resources will still need to use plain HTTP to make the connection to the proxy server.  (Once connected to the proxy the client will use the CONNECT method to establish a TLS connection via the proxy to the webserver which creates an end-to-end encrypted channel.)

In other words: you probably need to change the HTTPS_PROXY variable to:

```
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.330.100.100:3128/"
```

---

When you're required to use a proxy, that often means that also TLS traffic is controlled. You may need to install and enable your organisations CA certificate.

---

When you're required to use a proxy, that means that others in your organisation are required to do the same.

That means that you (or rather your proxy server,  will very quickly run into the docker rate limiting. See: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/